# How to use otf-font in ggplot2 graphics?

Tags: r, fonts, ggplot2, knitr

I want to use an otf-font in my ggplot2 graphics. I'm using Mac OS X 10.9. I found http://goo.gl/dFqJhV

But the experimental part won't work for me.

http://goo.gl/rNmIRR doesn't work either because I got lot's of errors compiling the branch. The mentioned branch seems to be too old.

The solution with cairo_pdf() (http://goo.gl/LcYFS6) does work but not for me, because I want to embed the graphics into a knitr file with output pdf and/or html.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [showtext](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext) package combined with `knitr` using the `fig.showtext=TRUE` option.

Assume that the OTF font has a **filename** "somefont.otf", and you want to use it in R through the family name "myfont" (can be an arbitrary character string). Below is an example of an Rmd file that can be compiled into PDF or HTML:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(showtext)
font.add("myfont", "somefont.otf")
```

```{r fig.showtext=TRUE, fig.width=7, fig.height=7}
plot(cars, family = "myfont")
```
````

Comment: Had been banging my head against the wall on this with a paper. Worked perfectly, especially when I moved the `fig.showtext = T` option into `knitr::opts_chunk$set()`. Thank you!

Comment: Is this in the documentation anywhere?