# knitr, cairo and ggplot2: font family 'Source Code Pro' not found in PostScript fontdatabase

Tags: r, fonts, ggplot2, knitr, cairo

Trying to fix the problem with otf-fonts I have (see [How to use otf-font in ggplot2 graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749826/r-how-to-use-otf-font-in-ggplot2-graphics)) I found that I can use these fonts with ggplot2.

Using knitr with Rmd-files is okay:

````
---
title: "FontTest"
author: "me"
date: "22. April 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=factor(gear))) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16, family="Arial"))
```
````

But when I want to use LaTeX (Rnw-files) I get an error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<>>=
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
library(ggplot2, quietly=TRUE)
@



<<>>=
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=factor(gear))) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16, family="Arial"))
@

\end{document}
```

Here's the error:

```
Writing to file test.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
 1 : echo keep.source term verbatim (test.Rnw:6)
 2 : echo keep.source term verbatim (test.Rnw:13)
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type
Calls: <Anonymous> ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Execution halted
```

I'm using Mac OS X Mavericks.

**Update**

I found a work around using Cairo:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}



<<>>=
  Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
library(ggplot2, quietly=TRUE)
library(Cairo)
@



<<dev='cairo_pdf'>>=

  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=factor(gear))) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16, family="Source Code Pro"))

@

\end{document}
```

But now I get lot's of warnings:

```
## Warning in grid.Call(LtextBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x,x$y, :  font family 'Source Code Pro' not found in PostScript fontdatabase
```

I would like to avoid suppressing these warnings. So what do I have to do to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: I was wondering why you have `\SweaveOpts`, so I found somewhat related question, check that out (Yihui's answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040064/knitr-compile-problems-with-rstudio-windows

Comment: Perhaps the 0 should be an O?

Comment: @tonytonov First I wondered why I always get this line back. But during my trial and error I switched to Sweave. But resetting it to knitr I still get the error: Quitting from lines 15-22 (test.Rnw) 
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type
Calls: knit ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Execution halted

Comment: @tonytonov I forgot to mention that the above error is without the \SweaveOpts line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

I use

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

and

```
<<plot, dev='tikz'>>
```

in my .Rnw file. Doing it this way I get the fonts of my LaTeX project in my plots.