# New font error with Showtext in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Since updating to the new version of `R 3.4`  I've developed a new error when printing `ggplot`'s using `showtext`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)

font.add.google("Lato")

p1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, price)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "Lato")
```

This normally works to print the plot:

```
showtext.auto()
ggsave(plot = p1, "trial.pdf")
```

But instead I get

```
Saving 5.2 x 5.83 in image
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

This is my `SessionInfo()`

[image: session_info_printscreen]

Comment: Interesting--downgrading to the previous version of R solves this problem.

Comment: Same errors in R 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling `showtext` under R 3.4

Comment: I'm currently running it under 3.3.3 and am seeing the error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749826/how-to-use-otf-font-in-ggplot2-graphics/30141197#30141197 helped me